# How to parse a raw signature from PolkadotJS in Substrate runtime

Tags: polkadot-js, runtime

The Polkadot claims pallet verifies and extracts an ethereum address from an `EcdsaSignature`. Is there a similar implementation for doing this with an `Sr25519Signature` signed by a wallet using PolkadotJS?

The API for PolkadotJS is below

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/sign-verify/

I'm curious if there are examples for implementing this directly inside of a Substrate runtime. I would like to take a raw signature and extract the public key account for verification.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in Schnorrkel/Ristretto x25519 or `sr25519` it's not possible to recover public key from the signature. You need to know both public key and message to verify it.

[This](https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel/blob/master/annoucement.md?plain=1#L59) from `schnorrkel` repo:

> In ECDSA, there are no known problems with using ecrecover and HDKD together, but using HDKD actually breaks both BLS signatures and the malleable Schnorr signatures that [support ecrecover.](https://www.deadalnix.me/2017/02/17/schnorr-signatures-for-not-so-dummies/).  We therefore use  non-malleable signatures that forbid ecrecover.